# Rails Conditional Select Contents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm populating a select tag dynamically within my form.  The select tag is populated by a query to `Payee`.  I have a couple fields I'd like to display as the text value of the element.  However it must be done conditionally. For example.

fields:

```
:company
:first_name
:last_name
```

I can concatenate those three in the text box like so:

```
f.select :payee_id, Payee.all.collect { |p| [p.company.to_s + " " + p.first_name.to_s + " " + p.last_name.to_s, p.id] }
```

The above doesn't work the way I desire. If `company` exists, I would like to leave out `first_name` and `last_name`.

if `company` is blank, I'd like to display only `first_name` and `last_name`

currently if `company` and `first_name` exist it concatenates the two together, which I do not desire.

I know how to query the database for each case separately, but I don't know how to  combine the results so the select tag will display correctly.

Here's what I have of my helper so far. I know it's currently a mess, but I need help understanding the method to get this done.

```
def expense_payee_id_field(f)
  @payee_with_company = Payee.where("company IS NOT NULL and company !='' ")
  @payee_without_company = Payee.where("(first_name != '' or last_name != '') and company = '' ")

  f.select :payee_id, Payee.all.collect { |p| [p.company.to_s + " " + p.first_name.to_s + " " + p.last_name.to_s, p.id] }
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just create a method in your `Payee` model that does this logic for you:

```
# Payee.rb

# I've extracted this into its own method
# because you very well may need it later
def full_name
  [first_name, last_name].join(" ")
end

# This can be written more concisely, but I've
# kept it as-is to allow for better readability
def display_name
  if company_name.blank?
    full_name
  else
    company_name
  end
end
```

Now, you can simply call `payee.display_name` and it will print the desired result.

Comment: One last question.  This works for NULL values but not empty strings.  What condition would test for empty strings as well as NULL? Should empty fields be NULL?

Comment: You would check for "blankness." I'll update my answer

Comment: You could also send compact to the [first_name, last_name] array in case one of them is null.